# 20.04 - Help with installation of Canon Pixma TR7620 printer

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, scanner, canon

I'm trying to install my new 4-in-one Canon Pixma TR7620 printer. I've gone through the 'add printer' routine and have selected  my printer under 'Canon' as the TR7600 Series, and this all seems to fit.  However, when I proceed from here I get an error message as follows:
CUPS SERVER ERROR
There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'server-error-internal-error'.
Can you please help me past this problem?  I'll be wanting to install the Fax and the Scanner once the printer itself is set up.

Comment: I just noticed a window that I had missed, it told me that the driver could not be found even though the TR7600 appeared at the bottom of the list under 'Canon'.  So I guess I'm lacking a driver - pretty basic!  However, I still have the problem of needing to set up this printer and make it fully functional.  I suspect that the TR7520 or TR7500 Series for which there seems to be a driver available in the US is probably the same basic printer but I could well be wrong.

Comment: If Ubuntu can't set up the printer natively, you'll probably need a proprietary driver. Strangely, Canon has a product page for this model number, but they do not have a support page, which is where you would find proprietary drivers, if they exist.  I suggest that you contact Canon's support and ask them if this product is supported on Linux, and if so, where you can obtain a driver. Specifically, you need a driver for 64-bit Debian-based Linux (deb).

Comment: accessing [this link](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/tr-series-inkjet/pixma-tr7520-wireless-office-all-in-one-printer?tab=drivers_downloads) from my Ubuntu 20.04 system shows a "IJ Printer Driver Ver. 5.50 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)" available for download.

Comment: @TonyB - just to point out that this link is for the PIXMA TR7520.  It's possible that the driver is compatible with the TR7620, but also possible that it won't work.

Comment: Thank you all. Actually, late last night I got onto Canon Canada Support website and found and downloaded IJ Printer Driver Ver.6.10 for Linux (debian Packagearchive).  I installed the  .... amd64.deb file.  This all worked and the printer now seems to be working fine.  So I guess this question is resolved.  Still struggling to get X-Sane and/or Document Scanner to locate the scanner but I guess that's another question.  Yes, I'm not as sharp as I used to be!

Comment: Please post the details of your solution as an answer. Ask Ubuntu's purpose is to host the largest library of questions and answers about Ubuntu.  Your answer will provide a solution to this problem which will help future visitors with the same question. Thanks in advance for your contribution. If you have another question you can click "Ask Question".  You can link to this one if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 0):

The help I needed was to do with the installation of a proper driver for the Canon Pixma TR7620 4-in-1 Printer.  It may be that the TR7620 is only sold in Canada.  The answer is to go to the Canon Canada Support website where on searching there are a number of drivers available for Linux based systems. I selected "IJ Printer Driver Ver. 6.10 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)".  Download the driver and then extract the files.  In the Packages folder I selected and installed the " ... amd64.deb" file to suit my 64bit system.  Follow on with the Add Printer routine - the printer will likely up as a Canon Pixma 7600 Series printer. FYI, The same support website also has scanner drivers.

Comment: That  support website does not provide any scanner driver capable of interworking with SANE. See https://wiki.debian.org/Scanner#canon.